javax SchemaFactory disable access to external entities not recognized
I am using javax SchemaFactory to parse an XML file. I get a SonarLint warning "Disable access to external entities in XML parsing.". The warning goes away when adding two properties "ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD" and "ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA". However, when parsing something I get the runtime error "Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.". Why is it not recognized and how to fix this? My code:
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;

public class MinimalExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        factory.setProperty(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
    }
}

I don't understand why those properties are not recognized and don't know what else to try.

What is the implementation class of the SchemaFactory that is instantiated? My guess would be that it's a shim designed to wrap some underlying schema factory, and people who write such shims often overlook the need to recognize these standard properties.

Incidentally, if you are processing a schema from a source that you trust, then you can ignore these warnings, and if it's from a source that you don't trust, then you might have bigger problems. Unfortunately lint checkers are rather unsophisticated about such distinctions.

@MichaelKay The implementation class? As you see in imports its "javax", so it comes straight from Oracle. The schemes are trusted. The XML-files that are evaluated within those schemes are not. I can't ignore the message because the SonarQube analysis must be clear of such critical issues for this project. Is this message a warning about the scheme files or the XML files are that processed?

javax.xml.validation.Schema is an interface, not an implementation. The whole point of the newInstance() factory mechanism is that you pick up whatever implementation is available at run-time, which might not be Oracle's implementation. Quite honestly, SonarQube analysis is a waste of space: it's picking up that you're not setting some pretty weak security properties, but it's failing to pick up that you might be loading a fake schema processor from anywhere.
